# Multiple Tags search query is getting results only by 1 tag match

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

In my table here

```
        posts                        tags
[  id    -     title  ]         [pid  -  tag]
[  1     -     echo   ]         [ 1   -  PHP]
[  2     -     for    ]         [ 1   -  PDO]
                                [ 2   -  PHP]
```

i do this query

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $tag = implode(",",$_POST['tags']);
    $query = "
    SELECT a.title FROM posts a
    INNER JOIN tags b ON a.id = b.pid
    WHERE b.tag IN (:tag)
    ";
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute(['tag' => $tag]);
    while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
        echo $row['title'];
    }
}
```

Here is what happens

If i select `[PHP]` only, i get the results `[echo - for]`

And if i selected `[PDO]` only, I get the result `[echo]`,

**But** if i selected `[php and pdo]` i get no results at all, And i was expecting to get the result `echo`. How can i solve my query?

Comment: For every word in a search you need a separate placeholder in a query. No options.

Comment: @u_mulder how exactly to do that?

Comment: https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, even though you'd think by now they would have covered this.. No you can't bind array's to a prepared statement.

Ultimately you have 2 options, provide it as a string direct to the query or use `FIND_IN_SET`

## Option 1:

```
$tags = implode(",",$_POST['tags']);
$inString = implode(',', array_fill(0, count($tags), '?'));
$query = $db->prepare('
    SELECT a.title FROM posts a
    INNER JOIN tags b ON a.id = b.pid
    WHERE b.tag IN(' . $inString . ')'
    );

foreach ($_POST['tags'] as $key => $tag){
    $query->bindValue(($key+1), $tag);
}
$query->execute();
```

## Option 2:

```
$tags = implode(",",$_POST['tags']);
$query = $db->prepare('
    SELECT a.title FROM posts a 
    INNER JOIN tags b ON a.id = b.pid
    WHERE FIND_IN_SET(b.tag, :array)'
    );
$query->bindParam('array', $tags);
$query->execute();
```

Comment: In matter of performance, `Option 2` is faster, correct? Since it does the job in the SQL itself.

Comment: Depends mainly on the size of your table, as option2 will not utilize your indexes.

Comment: I keep getting `Warning
: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`, Why is that? for `Option 1`

Comment: My bad, I put the wrong var there, it's attempting to loop the string where it should be looping the array $_POST['tags'] , changing it now.